# When piped with ls, grep in solaris is not working

Tags: linux, unix, grep, solaris, egrep

I am using the below command in solaris

```
ls -l | grep '*PROC*'
```

But it is not working. I have many files that contain "PROC" in their name like "XREF_PROC.complete" but when I use the above command its not showing any output. When I use `ls *PROC*` its working but not working with grep.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You don't need a quantifier, just grep for PROC:

```
ls | grep PROC
```

**long version**

The asterisk in your `ls` line, is not the same as the one in your  `grep` line.

When you have an unescaped asterisk on the command line, the shell will expand it before `ls` sees it, this is called [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). An asterisk alone expands to all files in the current directory, try for example `echo *` . The `*PROC*` glob will expand to all files containing PROC.

The asterisk you are using with `grep` *is* escaped with single-quotes, and thus will be interpreted by `grep`. However, `grep` uses [BREs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) by default (Basic Regular Expressions), where the asterisk works as a quantifier, and so requires some character or character class to quantify, e.g. `'.*'`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I use REDHAT unix servers and when I do `ls -l | grep *PROC*` it works fine. But not in solaris. So is this a unique case in solaris or am I missing somethinh

Comment: @sandywho: Notice that you are _not_ escaping the asterisks, this means the shell will expand `*PROC*` before grep sees it. This *only* works if only one file exists with PROC in its name. Always escape patterns given to grep!

Comment: you know this but it's worth mentioning 'cos your answer specifically brings up BREs., Grep can use EREs or PCREs too, though indeed in all of these, any regular expression, it'd be `.*` as with BREs. So it's not an issue of BRE/ERE/PCRE it's just the fact that it's a Regular Expression.

Comment: @sandywho type  `echo *`  see if the output is different in solaris, and how it difers.  `*` will expand to every file in the current directory (not exactly what you want but that's what * is doing when interpreted by the *nix shell). It's not like in the windows command line where the command always interprets the `*`.  Try `ls -l | grep '.*PROC.*'`   'cos `.*` is regex talk for any sequence of characters

Comment: @barlop In other words, if a command like `echo *` would take long enough to run (and were not an internal), you could find it in `ps x` and it would show up there as `echo file1 file2 file3 file4` instead of `echo *`

Comment: @sandywho : Redhat is not certified unix, it's unix-like OS, linux

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  yeah but that 'complifies' my point. though since my point was just that * expands, echo was really merely a safety thing, I could've simplified my point more than echo, but saying type just * enter i.e. . `$*<ENTER>` but    then if the first file was a command it'd execute it, so echo is safer